# Is there a way to morph a Laravel Eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `Detail` (represents order details) model that I'd like to morph to either a sales order detail or a purchase order detail. So I create a table that has a 'type' column, which would have a value of 'sale' or 'purchase'.

My question is, is there a way in Laravel that I could morph the Detail model to Sale and Purchase, so that, for example, if I call `App\Sale::all()` it would fetch `App\Detail::all()->where('type','sale')` ?

Comment: [Yes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: @MartinBean Can you be more specific?

Comment: Your `Detail` model should be morphable, and `Sale` and `Purchase` models should morph to it.

Comment: @MartinBean Is it the same as zianwar's answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't found an "official" way to morph a single class to another. I developed the following way that could be a solution.

First, define two models `Sale` and `Purchase` that extends `Detail`, and use the trait that will define later.

```
    class Sale extends Detail {
        use SaleTrait;
    }
```

Then, use [GlobalScope](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-global-scope-on-retrieving-a-model) to add constraints to query builder. Here are the steps:

1. Define a trait for `Sale` and `Purchase` model,

```
    trait SaleTrait {
        public static function bootSaleTrait()
        {
            static::addGlobalScope(new ActiveEventsScope);
        }
    }
```

2. Then define the scope. NOTE: here instead of implementing ScopeInterface, I extends [Sofa\GlobalScope](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/laravel-global-scope) which handles `remove()` method for me, so I only need to define `apply()` in the scope.

```
    class SaleScope extends GlobalScope
    {
        public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
        {
            $builder->where('type', 'sale');
        }
    }
```

3. Now I could use `App\Sale::all()` and `App\Purchase::all()` to only retrieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

#### Set the database tables:

You can set up your database tables in this structure :

```
purchases
    id - integer
    price - string

sales
    id - integer
    price - integer

details
    id - integer
    description - string
    detailable_id - integer
    detailable_type - string
```

#### Set your models:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Detail extends Model
{

    // Get all of the owning detailable models.
    public function detailable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Sale extends Model
{

    // Get all of the sales member's order details.
    public function details()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Detail', 'detailable');
    }
}

class Purchase extends Model
{

    // Get all of the purchase's order details.
    public function details()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Detail', 'detailable');
    }
}
```

#### Retrieve data :

And then you can retrieve your sales like this :

```
$sales = App\Sale::find(1);

foreach ($sales->details as $order_detail) {
    //
}
```

Same thing with purchases :

```
$purchases = App\Purchase::find(1);

foreach ($purchases->details as $order_detail) {
    //
}
```

> More about polymorphic relations : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: I don't know but it seems to me that polymorphic relations is not designed for situations like this. And this way actually requires additional tables in database which I am not in fond of.